# Displaying image generated by Paperclip in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am able to display image generated by Paperclip in Rails app, at DEVELOPMENT env,
E.g http://localhost:3000/system/shot/sample.png

However upon I migrate to PRODUCTION, http://xyz/system/shot/sample.png is not recognized. I am using Passanger running on Apache. Is there any config that I need to setup at prod env? 
And I've verified the physical folder and file exits at prod machine.

Note: i just check the production.log , and herewith the error

```
**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/shot/sample.png"):**
```

Looking at the error above, likely I need to do something in route.rb ; but strangely i am using same route.rb in DEV , and it works..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry,  it is false alarm, the image file was not yet created initially.

Answer (score 0):

do something like `which convert` and it should print out something.   if there is nothing, then  you know you need imagemagick.

Check that your imagemagick on your slice is set up to serve png's and jpgs too, while you are at it.

I use Gentoo and the built in package manager use flags turn off that stuff, so my pngs never showed.

Comment: hi pjammer, thanks for your comment, i understood this upload problem as well, but I overcome it, and now is "display" or probably routing issue..